# Excel avoid variable defined named cell from insert when selecting cell for formula?

Tags: excel

[image][image]I have many defined cells and am executing a formula for drag and apply for other adjacent cells.
Problem is, when I select a cell it inserts defined variable name and when drag and apply is used, the variable name stays instead of changing to the next adjacent cell. 
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to select a cell and input its cell location [image] rather than its variable defined name? [image]

Comment: Well definitely doable by just typing the cell location out manually.

Comment: The purpose of a named range is to be able to refer to a fixed location by that name. If you want a variable location you can't use named ranges. However, your idea is implemented in the structured referencing developed for using in tables. If you can put your data in a table you can use syntax like this, `=[@Column3]*[@Column1]` where the column names serve to identify the cell of that column in the current row - and the formula copies down to the entire table automatically.

Comment: @NikoTumi I don't quite follow what is happening with your situation. Please provide some data (what is in the columns you are looking at), what the formula is that you have right now (even if it doesn't give you what you want) and an example of what you want the formula to do

Comment: I added photos to hopefully clear up any confusion and posted somewhat of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled across kinda of a solution.

When selecting a cell, hold ctrl and gouble click it. 
You will get =A1,A1 
So, just delete the second term and done.
But there should be a simpler solution to this.